Upcoming site graduation: leaving beta on 2021-12-16
since the proposal in 2013, our site has steadily garnered interest and and influx of new community members. Igor also pointed out, that we probably owe the whole idea taking shape to Rolf pitching it over on Reddit.
As with so many topics, when you search for reverse engineering topics, often a Q&A from our site will pop up in the search engine of your choice.
Now, on December 16th (2021-12-16) our site will graduate and lose its beta label, similar to how it happened to other sites in 2019.
Congratulations to the whole community.
NB: More information will be shared, but suffice it to say for now that this will also mean our first moderator elections for the site.

It's official!
